# Reading ZFS snapshots from tape is slow

Tags: backup, zfs, gzip, tape

I backed up my a zfs snapshot to tape using

```
zfs send tank/vertex@2017-01-20 | pv -cCTrbB 1g | pigz -c | pv -cCTrbB 1g | dd of=/dev/nst0 bs=1M
```

and then read it back using

```
dd if=/dev/nst0 bs=1M | pv -c | gzip -dc | ztreamdump
```

and it's progressing at a peak speed of `39 MiB/s`, which is much slower than the `77 MiB/s` or so that it wrote at.

EDIT: I just tried filling the tape with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/nst0 bs=1M count=1k` and was then able to read it back at `99 MiB/s`.

Comment: What happens when you only do a raw read from tape? (e.g. just the dd to a file). If that is fast, what happens if you remove `pv` from the pipe? Etc. Just to break things down into small and testable parts.

Comment: @Hennes Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it both ways (raw `dd` with and without `pv` and the results were the same as the original case.

Comment: I don't know if that's the case but you use `pigz` to compress and `gzip` to decompress. The former can utilize many CPU cores. `man pigz` says that "decompression can't be parallelized". Maybe that's your bottleneck. Check the CPU usage during both writing and reading; compare to the first command where `pigz` is replaced by `gzip`. That's not an answer (yet) because I only guess.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You're right that is a potential bottleneck except that `gzip` decompression is much faster than compression. But by following Hannes' suggestion we can cut the compression program out of the test.

Comment: See my edit above, I just tried the test again with random input data instead of data from a zfs filesystem and was able to read it at full speed.

Comment: `gzip` decompression is much faster than compression – right. Still with enough processors `pigz` compression may win with `gzip` decompression, especially if you don't use `-9` or so to compress. I don't know how many cores you have in total. To measure decompression speed, place large chunk (the beginning) of your archive in memory (like `/dev/shm`), then `pv chunk | gzip -dc > /dev/null`.

Comment: What read speed do you get if you omit the `ztreamdump` at the end? Just throw the decompressed data at /dev/null and let us know what read speeds you get then. That would tell us if ztreamdump needs the extra time to process the data it is being fed.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I have odd results. `dd if=/dev/nst0 bs=1M | pv > /dev/null` yielded  50 MiB/s at the beginning of the tape and 36 MiB/s on the area immediately after which was the same data but encrypted to make sure it wasn't compressible.

Comment: I have a nagging feeling it could be a bad PCI card. That would explain the less than straightforward things that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues. 1) Are you using the same tape for both test ?

I'll try to give a long answer, as it took me time finding this info on LTO tapes.
This is one of the good reference on drive/tape inquiry by IBM hosted by Oracle named : *GA32-0450-07*.

My answer : Some LTO tapes are ***old-new*** (new and made quite a few years back but never used), already used and marked as ***new-re-certified*** or ***new-bad*** (new but not stored adequately during transportation/storage). Also, certain vendors may not mention re-certified and just advertise as a new tape.

[Fujitsu](http://www.fujifilmusa.com/press/news/display_news?newsID=880625) tried 50 re-certified tapes, 16 of them had "had unacceptably high read, write, and servo error rates, likely due to excessive wear and edge damage from mishandling or misaligned tape drive".

To check how many reads and loads the tape had or read-write errors, use `sg_logs -a /dev/st0` and look at section 30h. It will output lots of useful info!

I believe it's possible to overwrite the RFID chip on the tape, it's in it that all info are log. But if you ***burn-in*** your *new?* tape (write/read full tape) and check it back and it (`sg_logs`) has errors, you know that your tape is not in good shape.

Tip for new tapes : make a single large random file the size of the LTO tape and checksum it `sha512`, write it to tape, read it back from tape, check if checksum is still ok, and look at read/write speed. Compare error logs on drive/tape before and after. Don't forget to use `mbuffer` ! If all is good, you may put your tape in production. Burn-in is used on new HD, check blackblaze and their definition of burn-in : "This requires that every block on every drive is read and checked".

Monitor those numbers (from `sg_logs`) and if a tape has high errors, total data written / tapesize > 250 or load count nearing 3000 replace it.

You could still leave a copy of the data on it, but certain old tapes (used-ebay) of mine will only read back at 5-30MB/s because the drive has too many errors to correct (write is still full speed). But hey, still works, will have to check them back in 20-30 years to see if they are still readable. LTO tapes are reed solomon coded, so repairing some level of errors is possible. Some used tapes comes from extensive use backup libraries and may have been written once a week or once a day for a few years, so just check them to be sure you can trust it for your data. If you do mission critical backup, why not get them directly from HP or other official vendor. If it's just casual stuff and you can have it duplicated a few times on different inexpensive tapes, used LTO tapes can be worth it to save $$$. Then again, if you want daily or weekly backup, better get a *real new* tape.

Life expectancy of LTO from [HPe](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Tape-Libraries-and-Drives/How-often-should-LTO-tapes-be-replaced/m-p/3318090#M12149) : 
"The official text says: "Ultrium media is certified for 1 million passes or 260 full back ups and has a 30-year archival storage life."

That said, it would seem you should be able to have one tape last almost a full year of daily backups before seeing media errors."